# run time error 5 in VBA excel when working with array

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I use vba on excel 2007, OS: windows vista, to make calculation using kinematic wave equation in finite difference scheme. But, when it runs the run-time 5 (invalid procedure call or arguments) message appears. I really don't what is going wrong. Anyone can help?

```
Sub kwave()

Dim u(500, 500), yy(500, 500), alpha, dt, dx, m, n, so, r, f, X, L, K As Single

Dim i, j As Integer

dx = 0.1
dt = 0.01
L = 10
m = 5 / 3
r = 1
f = 0.5
n = 0.025
so = 0.1 'this is slope
alpha = 1 / n * so ^ 0.5

X = 0
For i = 0 To 100
Cells(i + 1, 1) = X
u(i, 1) = L - so * X
X = X + dx

Cells(i + 1, 2) = u(i, 1)
Next i



For j = 0 To 100
For i = 1 To 100
'predictor step
u(i, j + 1) = u(i, j) - alpha * dt / dx * (u(i + 1, j) ^ m - u(i, j) ^ m) + (r - f) * dt

'corrector step

K = u(i, j + 1) ^ m - u(i - 1, j + 1) ^ m '<<<<----- RUNTIME ERROR 5 HAPPENS AT THIS LINE

yy(i, j + 1) = 0.5 * ((yy(i, j) + u(i, j + 1)) - alpha * dt / dx * K + (r - f) * dt)


Next i
Next j




End Sub
```

Comment: Error occurs when `i = 99`, `j = 10`.  At this time `u(i, j + 1)` is negative and since `m` is not integer `u(i, j + 1) ^ m` is undefined and causes the error.

Comment: @chrisneilsen negative numbers can be raised to powers too.

Comment: @aStackOverflowUser not in excel. Read the help

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring the variables wrong- the array should store a double/single but it is defaulting to a variant.  See this article.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx -

> "Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement
>
> VBA allows declaring more than one variable with a single Dim
>   statement. I don't like this for stylistic reasons, but others do
>   prefer it. However, it is important to remember how variables will be
>   typed. Consider the following code:
>
> Dim J, K, L As Long You may think that all three variables are
>   declared as Long types. This is not the case. Only L is typed as a
>   Long. The variables J and K are typed as Variant. This declaration is
>   functionally equivalent to the following:
>
> Dim J As Variant, K As Variant, L As Long You should use the As Type
>   modifier for each variable declared with the Dim statement:
>
> Dim J As Long, K As Long, L As Long "

Additionally, when i = 99 and j = 10, u(99,11), which is j+1, produces a negative number.  Note that this does not fully cause the problem though, because you can raise negative numbers to exponents.  Ex, -5^3 = -125

Comment: 1) while what you say about variable declaration is true and should be corrected, it's not the cause of the error 2) the computer does _not _think "u" is the name of a function_ 3) exponentiation is not commutative.  The real cause of the error is trying to raise a negative number to a non-integer power.